# Using Haversine formula with Laravel eloquent and multiple where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, haversine

I need to fetch the data from table "properties" where I am storing the address of the property in longitude and latitude and other fields like construction_type,no_of_bedrooms,no_of_bathrooms.
Now I need to filter the data according to the nearest location given with passing other filters like construction_type,no_of_bedrooms,no_of_bathrooms.

I am using Haversine formula to fetch the nearest locations by given location.
I am having complexities in writing the laravel eloqent query when passing other filters as well.

```
$property = (new Property())->newQuery();
    if(\Request::get('Lat')!=null && \Request::get('Lng')!=null){
        $lat=\Request::get('Lat');
        $lng=\Request::get('Lng');
        $radius=200;
        $q="( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) )";
        $property->selectRaw("{$q} AS distance")->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$radius]);
    }

     if(\Request::get('construction_status')!=null){
         $property->where('construction_status', \Request::get('construction_status'));
     }
//other filters
return $property->get();
```

I expect the result as the properties with the nearest location given and other filters as well

Comment: What problem are you having? Do any of your other filters call `select()`?

Comment: I am having problem of writing raw sql query with `$property = (new Property())->newQuery();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to write your query like this**

```
$property = \DB::table('seller_properties');
    if(\Request::get('construction_status')!="any"){
             $property->where('construction_status', \Request::get('construction_status'));
         }
    //other filters
    if(\Request::get('Lat')!="" && \Request::get('Lng')!=""){
      $lat=\Request::get('Lat');
    $lng=\Request::get('Lng');
      $haversineSQL='( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) )';
      // resolve haversine formula here
    $property->whereRaw($haversineSQL . '<= ?', [25]);
     }
    return $property->get();
```

**NOTE:** `// dont initialize $property like this $property = (new Property())->newQuery();`

Comment: Thank you .. you made my day